# Unable to add contacts to specific group in android programmatically

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I am trying to create a group and contacts to that group using below code.
But with this code am able to create new group/lable but contacts are not added to that group.
Please suggest.

```
public String createGroupLatest(String name) {

    String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.Groups._ID,     ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE };

    try {
        ContentValues groupValues = null;
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        groupValues = new ContentValues();
        groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, name);
        groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.SHOULD_SYNC,true);
        cr.insert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, groupValues);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("########### Exception :",""+e.getMessage());
        return "1";
    }

    String groupID = null;
    Cursor getGroupID_Cursor = null;
    getGroupID_Cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,  GROUP_PROJECTION, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE+ "=?", new String[]{name}, null);

    getGroupID_Cursor.moveToFirst();
    groupID = (getGroupID_Cursor.getString(getGroupID_Cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    Log.v("TAG","==groupID=="+groupID);
    return groupID;


}
```

public Uri addToGroup(long personId, long groupId) {

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
            personId);
    values.put(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,
            groupId);
    values
            .put(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

    return getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);

}
```